# 'docker push ...' from Bitbucket Pipelines is very slow to my self-hosted docker registry

Tags: docker, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I am using Bitbucket Pipelines to build my docker image, and push to my self-hosted docker registry, which is located in China.

Is there any way I can speed up docker push from Bitbucket Pipelines. Otherwise, this features is almost useless.

Answer (score 1):

it seems [doubtful](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/CLOUD-3635) that much can be done to alleviate slow pushes given 1) bitbucket pipeline and 2) china registry constraints. you have at least three options if you could lift these constraints:

1. throw out bitbucket pipelines in favor of self-hosted source control management (gitlab/bitbucket server) and a self-hosted CI system that does pipelines as code (there are many to choose from these days, including jenkins)
2. throw out your self-hosted registry and use docker hub
3. self-host your registry in the US (bitbucket cloud and pipelines is probably US East?)

Comment: Thanks, Kevin. Your answer covers quite a lot, which is guidable for me.

Comment: Is there any "timeout" features within Bitbucket Pipelines, so that I can do more flow control to avoid failure caused by one step in pipelines steps.

Comment: I'm not seeing it after two minutes of searching.